How to export nvim configuration to EDITOR?
I saw this script yesterday and added this to my .bashrc file:
nvims() {
  items=("nvim" "nvim-chad" "nvim-lazy" "nvim-kickstart" "nvim-stan")
  config=$(printf "%s\n" "${items[@]}" | fzf --prompt=" Neovim Config  " \
    --height=~50% --layout=reverse --border --exit-0 --no-preview --color="bg+:#a7c080,fg+:black,prompt:#7fbbb3")

  if [[ -z $config ]]; then
    echo "Nothing selected"
    return 0
  elif [[ $config == "nvim" ]]; then
    config=""
  fi
  NVIM_APPNAME=$config nvim $@
  echo $config >|~/.config/nvims
  # echo "Has seleccionado $config"
}

# bind -x '"\C-a": nvims'

alias nvim-chad="NVIM_APPNAME=nvim-chad nvim"
alias nvim-lazy="NVIM_APPNAME=nvim-lazy nvim"
alias nvim-kickstart="NVIM_APPNAME=nvim-kickstart nvim"
alias nvim-stan="NVIM_APPNAME=nvim-stan nvim"
alias nvim='NVIM_APPNAME=$(cat ~/.config/nvims) nvim'

export NVIM_APPNAME=$(cat ~/.config/nvims)

It works fine, but I cannot make it work with other programs like yazi because it uses EDITOR as a variable, which makes more sense to me. I want to make EDITOR to read this too, but I don't know how. I tried adding at the end export EDITOR=$NVIM_APPNAME and sourcing bashrc again, but it doesn't seem to work.

export EDITOR=nvim should work.

I do not undersatnd. You present 5 aliases. Which command exactly should be used for EDITOR? First one? Second one?

Hi @Niloct, thanks for replying! I tried this before, but without export NVIM_APPNAME=$(cat ~/.config/nvims), and now it works, so thanks a lot!!
Hi, @Kam

I've also just seen that it's required to source ~/.bashrc at the end of the function so $EDITOR gets updated too, which I didn't take into consideration.
Hi, @KamilCuk, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, and thanks for replying too! I want $EDITOR to be 'NVIM_APPNAME=$(cat ~/.config/nvims) nvim', so it acts like all of these aliases depending on what I selected previously; but you're right, they are unnecessary!

Check your script with shellcheck. I suggest it could be much easier to just read NVIM_APPNAME from neovim configuration. This looks confusing.


Choose a directory ~/bin or ~/.local/bin

Add that directory to $PATH

Create a file in that directory named editor with the following content:
#!/bin/sh
NVIM_APPNAME=$(cat ~/.config/nvims) nvim "$@"


Set executable permissions on editor file you have created

Set export EDITOR=editor


